# How do i calculate a whole bunch of different scanner inputs?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm not quiet sure how to go about doing the calculations for this.  I have everything down right up until i'm trying to actually get the investment amount.  I know what i have right now is wrong, but google isn't being super helpful for me, and my book just does not have what i need in order to complete this darn thing.

Here what i have right now

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class InvestmentCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create a scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prompt user to enter investment amount
        Scanner amount = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Investment Amount");
        while (!amount.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.println("Only Integers");
            amount.next();
        }

        //Promt user to enter interest rate
        Scanner interest = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Interest Percentage in decimals");
        while (!interest.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.println("Just like before, just numbers");
            interest.next();
        }

        //Prompt user to enter number of years
        Scanner years = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Number of Years");
        while (!years.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.println("Now you are just being silly. Only Numbers allowed");
            years.next();

        }

        //Compute Investment Amount
        double future = amount * Math.pow((1 + interest), (years * 12));

        //Display Results
        System.out.println("Your future investment amount is " + future);

    }
}
```

Any assistance would be very very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

First of all `amount`, `interest` and `years` are `Scanners`, they are not numbers.  The `Scanner` could contain any number of different types of content so it's impossible for something like `Math.pow` to know what it should do with them

You need to assign the values you read from the user to some variables.

I'd start by using a single `Scanner`, say called `kb`...

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Then use this whenever you want to get a value from the user...

You input loops seem wrong to me, I'm not particularly experienced with the `Scanner`, so there is probably a better way to achieve this, but...

```
int invest = -1; // amount
double rate = -1; // percentage
int period = -1; // period
do {
    System.out.println("Only Integers");
    String text = kb.nextLine();
    try {
        invest = Integer.parseInt(text);
    } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
        System.out.println("!! " + text + " is not an integer");
    }
} while (invest == -1);
System.out.println(invest);
```

Once you have all the information you need, make your calculations with these primitive types...

```
double future = invest * Math.pow((1 + rate), (period * 12));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use 4 different scanners for this because you are reading from the same stream.... Your code should be something like this -

import java.util.Scanner;

class InvestmentCalculator {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     double amount=0;
     int interest=0;
     double years=0;
    // create a scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Prompt user to enter investment amount
    Scanner amount = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Investment Amount");
    while (!input.hasNextDouble()) {      // you say you only want integers and are           
                                          // reading double values??
        System.out.println("Only Integers");
        amount = input.nextDouble();   
    }

    //Promt user to enter interest rate
    System.out.println("Enter Interest Percentage in decimals");
    while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Just like before, just numbers");
      interest= input.nextInt();
    }

    //Prompt user to enter number of years
    System.out.println("Enter Number of Years");
    while (!input.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.println("Now you are just being silly. Only Numbers allowed");
      years=input.nextDouble();

    }

    //Compute Investment Amount
    double future = amount * Math.pow((1 + interest), (years * 12));

    //Display Results
    System.out.println("Your future investment amount is " + future);

}
```

}

Comment: Your calculation is still wrong...and didn't I say that 3 hours ago :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer  - "Your code should be something like this" - I didnt say "this is your code"..

Comment: I didn't say the code was, but I'm pretty sure I said that the OP didn't need to use different scanners and that one would suffice ;)